# How to import a txt full of symbols into LaTeX

Tags: import

I have a txt file that I want to import it into LaTeX.  How can I import the txt file without changing its format? In particular, the txt doc has a lot of symbols (it is the output of other programs), so LaTeX must ignore those symbols..is there any way to do this?

psd: My current solution is to convert txt to pdf, and then to import the Pdf into the LaTeX.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What do you mean with `txt` file? Is it a `.doc` file or a `.txt` file?

Comment: Have you heard of [XeLaTeX](http://tug.org/xetex/)? It's a unicode-based variant of LaTeX and with [the `unicode-math` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math) you can input most things directly as Unicode. It could be of helo for you ;)

Comment: cool, I will check XeLaTex, I am currently using pdfLaTex... I meant a .txt

Comment: Take in mind that LaTeX usually works with ASCII code and if you use symbols that are not included, then you must use the packages `inputenx` (instead `inputenc`) for LaTeX editor can read your symbols. And also the package `fontenc` for produce the document with the right symbols according to your codification.

Or as @tohecz suggested, use XeLaTeX. In any case be careful to ensure you editor recognize well your native codification for avoid problems.

Answer (score 3):

No problem with a modern engine like XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and a font containing the glyphs.

[image: texsxSymbolsInput]

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-Symbols.txt}
ä %00e4
ú %00fa
ẞ %1e9e
∋ %220b
ʤ %02a4
∏ %220f
ϗ %03d7
א %05d0
ᾧ %1fa7
⓴ %24f4
☙ %2619
 \end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}
Some normal text, let's input the Symbols

\verb!\input{\jobname-Symbols.txt}!

\input{\jobname-Symbols.txt}
\end{document}
```